# Inequalities in a circle

Tags: geometry

Can anyone help me resolve this problem I've tried and I can't seem to figure it out.

[image]

Comment: Hints: (1) the triangle PAB is equilateral (why?), and (2) the arc from A to C is twice as long as the arc from A to B.

Comment: It looks like you have labeled one of the angles $30$ degrees. That's a good start. See what other angles you know. Look for useful right triangles.

Comment: @David K I know the triangle is isosceles with 2 30° angles amd 120 for the other angle, but I don't know how to solve for the base, I've tried making a radius from point P to point B which is 8in

Comment: Generally if you have an isoceles triangle, if you drop a perpendicular from the vertex between the equal sides ($B$ in this question) to the opposite side ($AC$ in this question), it divides the isoceles triangle into two congruent right triangles. Then if you know the sine or cosine of one of the angles, and the length of a side of the triangle, you can use those facts to find the lengths of the other sides.

Answer (score 1):

There are two equilateral triangles.
[image]

Comment: You can also use the cosine rule for triangle $APC$ and you will get the length of $AC$.